First order PDEs
I am trying to self-study PDEs.
I came across a way to solve a first order PDE but I am not sure if I am missing out something (are there any cases which this method cant handle? Or am I missing something in the way I wrote it?)
Now let me write what I understand in order to see if I am missing something.
Consider the PDE:
$$a(x,y) u_x + b(x,y) u_y =f(x,y,u)$$
Assuming $a$ and $b$ are non-zero functions (if one of them is zero, imply the same method anyway) we can divide by $b$ to obtain:
$$A(x,y) u_x + u_y = F(x,y,u)$$
Look for some $s$ such that we have $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ and demand that $\dfrac{du}{ds}=F$, that means, using the chain rule:
$$
\frac{du}{ds}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\frac{dx}{ds}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{ds} \Rightarrow \\
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\dfrac{dy}{ds}=1 & (1) \\
\dfrac{dx}{ds}=A(x,y) & (2)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
From $(1)$ we obtain $y=s+c=y(s)$ and using this $y(s)$ in $(2)$ we get the ODE $\frac{dx}{ds}=A(x,y(s))$ which we can solve using ODEs methods. Now recall the chain rule, use $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ from the ODE to finally get $\frac{du}{ds}=F(x(s),y(s),u)$ and solve this using ODEs methods, now all we have to do is to use the boundary condition to obtain $u(x,y)$ but am not sure if it actually keeps all the information we used when we parameterized, therefore I would appreciate if you can show some solved examples.
Please note that I am not feeling confident about this method so please forgive me if I made some serious mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

$$A(x,y) u_x + u_y = F(x,y,u)$$
You have correctly written the system of characteristic ODEs :
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\dfrac{du}{ds}=F\\
\dfrac{dy}{ds}=1  \\
\dfrac{dx}{ds}=A(x,y) \\ 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This is equivalent to
$$\dfrac{dx}{A(x,y)}=\dfrac{dy}{1}=\dfrac{du}{F}$$
This is the Charpit-Lagrange systhem of characteristic ODEs written on usual form.
To go further look at the many papers about "Method of Characteristics", for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics
You can found a lot of examples on StackExchange/Mathematics/First Order PDEs.
